# unable to activate logs on azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an active directory called on azure. This tenant has Azure AD Premium P2 license. I am trying to enable logs on this directory. I believe P2 license is required to enable logging. In the Active directory view when I try to enable logs, following error is dispalyed.

**"Log Analytics integration not enabled
This Azure AD tenant is not currently enabled to send logs to Log Analytics. Please click the link below to learn about how to turn on this feature."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Log Analytics to work you must:

- Create a Log Analytics workspace within your subscription
- Configure AD to send log events to Log Analytics

For details see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-install-use-log-analytics-views

Comment: I have log analytics worksapce enable but the susbcription there is as:esource group
(change)
:
adfsmigration
Status
:
Active
Location
:
East US
Subscription
(change)
:
Azure subscription 1. So does this workspace also need Azure AD Premium P2 license? The tenant and active directory does have that license.

Comment: You do not need  Azure AD Premium P2 license for log analytics to work.

Comment: Is your user global administrator or security administrator for the Azure AD tenant?

Comment: both adfsmigration.onmicrosoft.com
Your role
Global administrator and 6 other roles
More info
Azure AD Premium P2